# Finding probability density function for bivariate

Tags: probability

$Y_1$ and $Y_2$ is uniform over the region $0 \leq y_1 \leq 1$ , $0 \leq y_2 \leq 1$, and $0 \leq y_1 + y_2 \leq 1$. Let $U = Y_1 + Y_2$. I'm having trouble finding the probability density function for $U$. My set up is this, but I don't know what function I am supposed to integrate. Any help would be great thanks!

$$\int_0^1\int_0^{u-y_1}\,dy_2\,dy_1$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways you could do this, but one way I like is to look at the CDF of $U$:  $$\Pr[U \le u] = \Pr[Y_1 + Y_2 \le u] = \int_{x = 0}^u \int_{y = 0}^{u - x} f_{Y_1,Y_2}(x,y) \, dy \, dx,$$ where $f_{Y_1,Y_2}(x,y)$ is the joint density:  what is this function?  Then differentiate with respect to $u$ to obtain the PDF.

Comment: Okay awesome, I see now that my area of integration was off. But I'm lost as to how to find $f(x,y)$ isnt $fy_1 = 1$ and $fy_2 = 1$?

Comment: Got it, answered my own question - facepalm.